# Properly setup Intellij typescript code completion

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, ionic2

I have this new Ionic 2 project and I am having trouble with code completion, mainly auto-imports and go-to files (on `templateUrl` value click, for example).

For instance, the suggestion box for `OnInit` from `@angular/core, is coming like that:

[image: Code Completion for OnInit]
Now if I try to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the `lot-zone-detail.page.html` "link", it won't work either.

I want to know how to setup this whole thing properly, my guess is that it is related to `tsconfig.json` file.

here is mine:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es2015"
      ],
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
      "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
  }
```

Its default from ionic cli new project.

And here is my Intellij configurations:
[image: Intellij config]

Comment: import suggestions on your screenshot come from Typescript service... Idea's own auto-import suggests a single import here - `import {OnInit} from "@angular/core"`. Navigation to template files also works fine for me... Is `lot-zone-detail.page.html` located in the same folder as the component .ts file? as you don't see suggestions, etc. from Idea, it seems that indexing hasn't yet completed

Comment: Yes it is :( that sucks